# Can the user navigate away during an awaited DisplayAlert

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

Apologies if this sounds like a stupid question, but I'm just curious.

Say I have this:

```
async void buttonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sure = await DisplayAlert("Confirm", "Are you sure?", "Ok", "Cancel");
    // Can the user navigate away before execution gets to this point?
}
```

See my understanding of `async/await` is that the UI becomes responsive as soon as an `await` is hit. So in theory, ***as*** the alert is being displayed, the user can actually tap the back button for example, and go back to the previous page?

Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when you have a `DisplayAlert` with await, it's waiting for your responce. When you tap on back button, the responce of `DisplayAkert` would be `null` (in your case, `sure` param value is `null`), also you're just close your alert, and that's all. If you want to go back to the previous page from your current page, where you call your `DisplayAlert`, I think you'll need to create custom alert, like [PopupPage](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` doesn't make the UI responsive. It simply tells the code to wait at that point for the awaited method to complete.

For example:

```
async void SomeMethod()
{
    // Do some stuff

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Task.Delay(1000);

    // Do more stuff
}
```

In the method above, the code will do some stuff and then block until the **first** `Task.Delay` completes. Then, it will proceed to do more stuff.

If you do not have an `await` (as with the **second** `Task.Delay`, the code will simply carry on without waiting for the **second** `Task.Delay` to complete. In fact, you should get a warning about that. The total time the method above will wait for is **1 second**, because only the **first** `Task.Delay` method is awaited.

---

Regarding the question of navigating away as the dialog is getting displayed, yes it is entirely possible. If the user were to super-rapidly tap the back button just before the dialog displays, it will navigate to the previous page and show the dialog (unless the back button closes the app, in which case the dialog will not show).